# Expand property in hashtable

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, hashtable

I'm having a simple issue with a script, where I want to run a GCI against a remote server, issue is, the value is combined with another hashtable property, so the GCI fails.

The script reads entries from a two-column .csv, the headers are "server" and "platform"

Here's what I've got:

```
$ShortDate = (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
$CheckServer = @{}
$serverObjects = @() # create a list of server objects

Import-Csv $Dir\Servers.csv | ForEach {  
    $CheckServer.Server = $_.Server
    $CheckServer.Platform = $_.Platform

    if (GCI \\$_.Server\c$\log\Completed_Summary_*.html -EA 0 | where {$.LastWriteTime -ge "$ShortDate"}) {
        Write-Host "FOUND"
    } # end of IF GCI
} # end of For-Each

$serverObjects += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $CheckServer
```

The problem is that the entry for `$_.Server` should be SERVER1, SERVER2, SERVER3, etc, all the entries in the servers.csv, instead, the values for both `$_.Server` and `$_.Platform` are combined.  Such as:

```
Write-Host "Checking" \\@{Server=SERVER1; Platform=PLATFORM_1}.Server\c$\log\Completed_Summary_*.html
```

it should show as follows:

```
Write-Host "Checking" \\SERVER1\log\Completed_Summary_*.html
```

How do I un-combine them so that the GCI command works?

Comment: Try:
`ForEach ($Server in $_.Server) {if (GCI \\$Server\c$\log\Completed_Summary_*.html -EA 0 | where {$.LastWriteTime -ge "$ShortDate"}) {Write-Host "FOUND"}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PowerShell only does simple variable expansion inside strings. For more complex expressions like index operations or accessing object properties/methods it would insert the stringified value of the array or object variable and leave the rest of the operation untouched.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $array = 23, 42
PS C:\> Write-Host "some $array[1] or other"
some 23 42[1] or other
PS C:\> $object = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{Foo=23; Bar=42}
PS C:\> Write-Host "some $object.Foo or other"
some @{Bar=42; Foo=23}.Foo or other
```

To avoid this you need to either:

- assign the resulting value to a variable first and use that variable in the string:

  ```
  $value = $array[5]
  Write-Host "some $value or other"

  $value = $object.Foo
  Write-Host "some $value or other"
  ```
- use a [subexpression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) (`$(...)`):

  ```
  Write-Host "some $($array[5]) or other"
  Write-Host "some $($object.Foo) or other"
  ```
- use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`):

  ```
  Write-Host "some {0} or other" -f $array[5]
  Write-Host "some {0} or other" -f $object.Foo
  ```

Comment: How would i make the above work with my existing script? I tried write-host "checking $($CheckServer[1])" and write-host "checking $($ServerObjects[1])" .. and neither produced a result.

Comment: `$CheckServer` is a hashtable, not an array, and `$ServerObjects` is just an empty array, because your code never populates it. That's why both your attempts don't work. With the code from your question you'd just need to change `\\$_.Server\c$\log\Completed_Summary_*.html` to `"\\$($_.Server)\c$\log\Completed_Summary_*.html"`. However, judging from what you posted in your question that isn't your actual (or at least not your complete) code.

Comment: Correct, it's a hashtable, i've added the final line of the script which was missing, where all the $ServerObjects are collected.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. You're modifying a hashtable inside your loop, then append a custom object created from the hashtable to an array *after* the loop. That will put just a single object with the data from the last iteration into the array. What is your code trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: It comes from a template i've been using for about a year, it's worked fine for every other example function i've used it for, however, there's always room for improvement with PowerShell :-) I'm open to re-writing it based on the methods you provided. The idea of the template i'm using is to add elements to the hashtable / array as different tests are run. Collecting them all at the end to be sent to .csv/grid-view or emailed out.

Comment: That sounds an awful lot like adjusting your problem to a solution you already have rather than the other way around. That's a common anti pattern called ["Golden Hammer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_hammer). You may want to consider posting a new question where you describe the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: you are totally correct, the template is 1 year old, and needs to be updated. I'll review some other means by which data is imported from .CSV's and stored/export from arrays. If needs be, i'll post a new question and link it here later tonight/tomorrow. Thx again for pushing me in the right direction :-)

Comment: As requested, i've posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881060/import-csv-with-headers-scan-for-log-on-remote-servers-add-data-to-array-expo. Any help from those who posted/contributed to the original question is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

modify like it

```
$ShortDate = Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0
$CheckServer = @{}
$serverObjects = @() # create a list of server objects
$Dir="C:\temp"

Import-Csv $Dir\Servers.csv | ForEach {  
    $CheckServer.Server = $_.Server
    $CheckServer.Platform = $_.Platform

    if (GCI "\\$($_.Server)\c$\log\Completed_Summary_*.html" -EA 0 | where {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $ShortDate}) 
    {
        Write-Host "FOUND"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thx , i tried this out, but I didn't work.  I get "The term '$.LastWriteTime'" over and over again.

Comment: but i was corrected $_.LastWriteTime' in my code, and this code work on my pc